# JS event listner on int-only CSS class

Tags: javascript, php, css

I have the following problem:

I have the following code in PHP:

```
<?php
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($floating_ips_json["floating_ips"]); $i++){
?>

<tr class="details-control-<?php echo $i; ?> cursor-pointer">
<td>Test</td>
<td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
</tr>

<script>
$('#table-overview').on('click',
'tr.details-control-<?php echo $i; ?>',
function() { ... }
</script>

<?php
}
?>
```

So the class of  is: details-control-1, details-control-2 and so on

But it doesn't work. If I use words-only for the details-control class, it works fine.

The goal is to create a table and trigger a JS action when a row is clicked.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What is the exact JS being output?

Comment: Why would you create a separate handler for each row to begin with?

Comment: (And why does it say "int-only CSS class" in the title? How is `details-control-123` "int-only", exactly ...?)

Comment: rather than giving it a different class why not just give them all the same class and have one script binding to that one class?  if you need to do something with the counter then put it in a data attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use a class and the power of jQuery

```js
$(function() {
  const $table = $("#table-overview");
  const $rows = $(".details-control", $table)
  $rows.on("click", function() {
    $rows.removeClass("active")
    $(this).addClass("active");
  })
})
```

```css
.details-control {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table-overview">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="details-control">
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="details-control">
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="details-control">
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```